# Unable to Increase Column size

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I need increase column size of the table , i am using below query to increase the size but i am getting below error

```
Alter Table Tabl1 Alter Column Col1 VarChar(6) Not NULL
```

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object 'Tabl1'  is dependent on column 'Col1'.
>   Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The statistics '_WA_Sys_Col1_5070F446' is dependent on column 'Col1'.
>   Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Col1 failed because one
>   or more objects access this column.

Because of same table as a dependency on the column

need help on this

Comment: I am using SQL server 2000 version database

Comment: Looks like you have some process using this table. Check in activity monitor.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server automatically adds statistics to a table over time to use when it parses a query and builds a query plan.  You have to drop the statistic to change the column.  For instance:

```
drop statistics [dbo].[Tabl1].[_WA_Sys_Col1_5070F446]
```

However, you should use SSMS to view the columns that are in the `_WA_Sys_Col1_5070F446` statistics before you drop it so that you can recreate it.  Something like this:

```
create statistics [_WA_Sys_Col1_5070F446] on [dbo].[Tabl1]([Col1])
```

But there may be more columns..., so be sure to find out which need to be included before you drop it.

You can run this SQL to find most of the dependencies, it doesn't report the statistics dependencies, but it catches most of the others:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(d.object_id) AS SP_Or_Function, OBJECT_NAME(d.referenced_major_id) AS TableReferenced
FROM   sys.sql_dependencies AS d INNER JOIN
       sys.all_sql_modules AS m ON m.object_id = d.object_id
where  OBJECT_ID(N'Tabl1') = d.referenced_major_id
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(d.object_id), OBJECT_NAME(d.referenced_major_id)
ORDER BY SP_Or_Function, TableReferenced
```

You can find all statistics used by a given table with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
OBJECT_NAME(s.[object_id]) AS TableName,
c.name AS ColumnName,
s.name AS StatName,
s.auto_created,
s.user_created,
s.no_recompute,
s.[object_id],
s.stats_id,
sc.stats_column_id,
sc.column_id,
STATS_DATE(s.[object_id], s.stats_id) AS LastUpdated
FROM sys.stats s JOIN sys.stats_columns sc ON sc.[object_id] = s.[object_id] AND sc.stats_id = s.stats_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.[object_id] = sc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = sc.column_id
JOIN sys.partitions par ON par.[object_id] = s.[object_id]
JOIN sys.objects obj ON par.[object_id] = obj.[object_id]
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(s.OBJECT_ID,'IsUserTable') = 1
AND (s.auto_created = 1 OR s.user_created = 1)
AND object_id(N'Tabl1') = s.[object_id]
```

Thanks to SQLAuthority for the last two SQL queries:

[SQL SERVER – Get the List of Object Dependencies – sp_depends and information_schema.routines and sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities (Gabriel's post)](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/04/sql-server-get-the-list-of-object-dependencies-sp_depends-and-information_schema-routines-and-sys-dm_sql_referencing_entities/)

[SQL SERVER – Find Details for Statistics of Whole Database – DMV – T-SQL Script](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/06/29/sql-server-find-details-for-statistics-of-whole-database-dmv-t-sql-script/)

Comment: I tried this method also but no luck and i dropped all view which are accessing this column still no luck any other method

Comment: Does SQLSvr2000's SSMS let you view/edit the table and script the entire change for you?  Later versions of SSMS script the drop of all dependencies, the change itself, and the recreation of all dropped dependencies.

Comment: Yes i am using sql server 2005 ssms where my database version is sql server 2000, i dropped all views,statistics  which are dependent on that column but still getting this error The object 'tabl1' is dependent on column 'col1'

Comment: Would you update your question with the SQL that you are using to change the table?

Answer (score 0):

Here is quote from SQL Server 2000 help:

> > ALTER COLUMN
> >
> > The altered column cannot be:
> >
> > .....
> >
> > - Used in an index, unless the column is a varchar, nvarchar, or varbinary data type, the data type is not changed, and the new size is
> >       equal to or larger than the old size.
> > - Used in statistics generated by the CREATE STATISTICS statement. First remove the statistics using the DROP STATISTICS statement.
> >       Statistics automatically generated by the query optimizer are
> >       automatically dropped by ALTER COLUMN.  .....